# Monterey 12.6 and Conda Environment Issue

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, conda, macos-monterey

After the upgrade to Monterey 12.6, my IDE, VS Code, cannot locate any of the packages in my conda environments. I checked echo $PATH and all paths remains. All env files are also present in the directories. I am not sure what is the exact problem.

Any suggestions for diagnosis or solution is much appreciated.

A search on stackoverflow shows a few recent posts with the similar problems after updating to Monterey 12.6:

[All Python scripts stopped working: path changed in all projects after macOS Monterey 12.6 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73722967/all-python-scripts-stopped-working-path-changed-in-all-projects-after-macos-mon)

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725316/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cookiecutter)

[Update of Xcode removes all Python packages on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716563/update-of-xcode-removes-all-python-packages-on-macos)

[Xdebug not starting in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73722565/xdebug-not-starting-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the jupyter extension in VS Code then install jupyter notebook again when prompted did the trick.